# Disable Responsiveness

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дизайн

А почему у нас такой опции нету?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369427/1991579

Comment: Может потому что отзывчивого дизайна нет? Я так понимаю это внедрят также с сайдбаром и другими "приятными" новшествами.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov хм, похоже на правду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тоже задавал вопрос о том, что это за зверь на MSE: [What is the “Responsiveness”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311366/339911)

А об ожидании прихода на сайт я спросил Joe Friend (он занимается активно передизайниванием сайтов SE) в комментарии, был получен такой [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314345/unable-to-upload-an-image-or-even-close-upload-popup-when-responsive-design-is-o/314421#comment1030490_314421):

> In the next week or so we will roll out the new theme & responsiveness on at least one localized site (to flush out bugs) and shortly thereafter on all of them.

Как можно заметить, с 21 августа прошло уже почти три недели, но я еще не наблюдаю этой опции ни на одном из локализованных сайтов. Видимо, возникли какие-то сложности, но процесс идёт и до нашего сайта это фича должна добраться рано или поздно.