# Responsiveness - как переведём?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, адаптивный-дизайн

Недавно нам наконец-то подвезли [адаптивный дизайн](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/176217) и в подвале сайта появились [ссылки вида](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7821/176217):

- Disable Responsiveness
- Enable Responsiveness

В связи с этим возник вопрос — как лучше перевести термин:

> Responsiveness

Предлагайте ваши варианты, голосуйте за существующие.

Comment: резиновость :-D

Comment: @Grundy «ruSO не резиновая». УткаУчитсяУму бы оценил.

Comment: @alexolut где ещё это слово используете?

Comment: @Suvitruf какое?

Comment: @alexolut Responsiveness)

Comment: @Suvitruf транзифекс нашел только пару мест. Или вопрос про интернет в целом?

Comment: @alexolut про транс. Если оно только в 1 месте используется, то можно не париться, что в другом месте что-то сломается и забить на дословный перевод.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант — использовать фразу:

> Адаптивный дизайн

Это более очевидное название, хотя и не соответствует переводу. К тому же, уже есть одноименная метка на Мете.

Comment: Это не вполне корректный термин, поскольку выключается не только адаптивность, но вообще любая подстройка под ширину окна браузера.

Comment: Напомню, отзывчивый дизайн - это комбинация адаптивного и резинового дизайнов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov то есть нужен еще вариант «Отзывчивый дизайн»?

Comment: Возможно, и правда нужен. Но я бы не стал его предлагать, поскольку старый дизайн после нажатия на эту кнопку не возвращается :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда предлагать буду я :)

Answer (score 1):

На текущий момент я перевёл как:

> Отзывчивость

На сайте не появилось ещё, так как нужно время, но есть сомнение в понятности данного перевода. То есть у не знакомых со спецификой участников будут возникать вопросы.

Comment: Мне этот нравится

Comment: Какую отзывчивость? Чего отзывчивость? Тем, кто не в курсе последних изменений, будет непонятно.

Comment: @Arhad думаете, англоязычным участникам с "responsiveness" понятнее? Но вообще я об этом как раз написал в ответе.

Comment: Почему этот вариант выбрали, если за "адаптивный" больше проголосовало людей?

Comment: Потому что перевод добавлен был еще ДО голосования (о чем сказано в ответе). Сейчас можно изменить.

Answer (score -3):

По результатам обсуждения в [комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8033/responsiveness-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bc/8035#comment33140_8035) появился еще один возможный вариант:

> Отзывчивый дизайн

Answer (score -3):

Литературный перевод именно этого слова не знаю, но можно пойти от обратного, частично изменив смысл фраз на противоположный:

> Disable Responsiveness → Включить фиксированный макет.
>
> Enable Responsiveness → Отключить фиксированный макет.

Comment: Макет - это, всё же, что-то на стадии проектирования. По крайней мере, для меня)

Comment: Данный вариант можно улучшить, заменив слово "макет" на "разметка", будет вполне неплохая альтернатива текущему лидеру ("Адаптивный дизайн")

Comment: @AK Разметка — это  том числе и про HTML-разметку. Как по мне, будет путаница. Но и «макет» тоже неоднозначен, на что указал Suvitruf.

Comment: Тогда всё-таки самый подходящий именно вариант на основе Responsiveness -> Адаптивный